# Linq Group by specific day interval?

Tags: c#, linq, datetime, group-by

I have following line to group my collection:

```
group c by new { date = GetGroupingDateKey(DateRangeType, c.ReadDate), name = c.Name } into g
```

and I use following function to get grouping date key:

```
private static DateTime GetGroupingDateKey(MeterReadingsTimeIntervals DateRangeType, DateTime Date)
{
    DateTime date = new DateTime();
    switch (DateRangeType)
    {
        case MeterReadingsTimeIntervals.Hourly:
            date = new DateTime(Date.Year, Date.Month, Date.Day, Date.Hour, 0, 0);
            break;
       case MeterReadingsTimeIntervals.Daily:
            date = new DateTime(Date.Year, Date.Month, Date.Day, 0, 0, 0);
            break;
        case MeterReadingsTimeIntervals.Weekly:

            // ???

            break;
        case MeterReadingsTimeIntervals.Monthly:
            date = new DateTime(Date.Year, Date.Month, 1, 0, 0, 0);
            break;
        case MeterReadingsTimeIntervals.Yearly:
            date = new DateTime(Date.Year, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
            break;
    }

    return date;
}
```

But I dont know about weekly grouping(it may be specific day intervals, 10 days,15 days, etc.). How can I group weekly? Should I use another way to group data?

Thanks in advice.

Comment: How do you define "week"? Is Monday 31st December 2012 in the same week as Tuesday 1 January 2013? Is a Sunday in the same week as the Monday that immediately follows it?

Comment: Side-note: I recommend following the .net naming conventions, where parameters start with a lowercase letter (camelCase).

Comment: @MarkByersweek, week is not important. It may be a specific day intervals.(for exam: 10 days, 15 days)

Comment: You could use the DayOfYear property if you just want to group into arbitrary sized day intervals.

Comment: @JamesGaunt, is there code example?

Comment: @AliRızaAdıyahşi So you don't care on which week-day the week starts? And a week that contains dec 31 and jan still counts as a single week?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the helper function

```
int DaysFromLast(DateTime date, DayOfWeek dow)
{
    return (7 + date.DayOfWeek - dow) % 7;
}
```

you can use

```
var date = Date.Date;
date = date.AddDays(-DaysFromLast(date, DayOfWeek.Monday));
```

for a week starting on a Monday, and so on.

For arbitrary intervals, you'll need a constant start date (preferably back in the past); then

```
var date = Date.Date;
date = date.AddDays(-((date - startDate).Days % numberOfDaysInInterval));
```

Comment: I think this is the answer that my expected. But I cant understand "startDate".

Comment: `startDate` needs to be some arbitrary date, back in the past, from which your cycle of 10- or 15- day intervals will run - like an anchor point.

Comment: That's a property! `(oneDate - anotherDate)` results in a [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx), and the [`TotalDays` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totaldays.aspx) gives the length of the timespan in fractional days.

Comment: You could (in this case) equivalently use [`Days`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.days.aspx) - I think I'll change it to this so everything's a whole number.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe like this:

```
date = Date.AddDays(-((Date.DayOfWeek - DayOfWeek.Monday +7)%7));
date = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, date.Day, 0, 0, 0);
```

If you consider Monday start of the week.

You can try it using this code:
**EDIT** Code edited after @Rawling suggestion, check the comments

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
dt = dt.AddDays(-((dt.DayOfWeek - DayOfWeek.Monday + 7)%7));
dt = new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day, 0, 0, 0);//today is Friday and it will show Monday at the end.
```

Comment: This doesn't consider Monday the start of the week. It'll _add_ one day to Sunday values.

Comment: Why a downvote? It will always set the date to the Monday of the desired week.

Comment: @Rawling I tried it and works perfectly. You should try it yourself.

Comment: No it won't. If you have a Sunday, `Date.DayOfWeek` is `0` and `DayOfWeek.Monday` is `1`. Then `Date.DayOfWeek - DayOfWeek.Monday` is `-1` so you _add_ one day to `Date`. Thus it stores a Sunday with the following Monday, effectively making the week start on the Sunday!

Comment: @Rawling Yes you are totally right, I thought that DayOfWeek enum starts with Monday, now checked it and you're right. I'll edit the answer. thank you.

Comment: OK, sorry for being a little brusque :)

Comment: No It's fine, we shouldn't give partially correct or wrong answers. The best reputation isn't the number that stands next to our names but the code that we write here. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The week is dependent on the kind of calendar that you're using and its rules. Some have the first week of the year start on the first Monday of the year, some on Sunday, etc, there are differences.

You can use [GregorianCalendar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.gregoriancalendar.aspx) for instance and its method GetWeekOfYear(DateTime).

```
case MeterReadingsTimeIntervals.Weekly:
  var gc = new GregorianCalendar();
  return gc.GetWeekOfYear(Date);
```

Now for this to work you have to make the return type of your method object or force the weekinfo into the same DateTime (set it to Monday of the found week),